# My theme's font is giving some problem !! It showing insecure content blocked. Tell me how to repair it?

Tags: wordpress

My theme's font is giving some problem !! It showing insecure content blocked. Tell me how to repair it ??

Console is showing problem in this - http://mazhinaukri.in/wp-content/themes/donovan/assets/fonts/raleway-v12-latin-ext_latin-regular.woff2 there are 42 same files which showing problematic

Answer (score 0):

You have SSL for your website but the page is requesting content with **http** that's why it is showing that error.

To fix this there are two ways

1. Find all the links that are making **http** request change them to **https**
2. Install A plugin which automatically converts **HTTP** request to **https**

I recommend this plugin **Really Simple SSL -https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/**